# Java jar "manifest.mf (No such file or directory)" MacOS

Tags: java, jar, compilation

I am trying to create a jar file for a simple 'hello world' program but have not been successful.

Here are the steps I have taken:

- My working directory is desktop/test
- Created class file with javac
- Created manifest.mf with 'Main-Class: Main' and an empty line below
- An 'ls' shows 'Main.class  Main.java manifest.mf'
- Ran 'jar -cvfm test.jar manifest.mf Main.class' and received the error in the title
- Also tried 'jar -cvf test.java Main.class' but got 'Main.class : no such file or directory' and it claims to add a manifest but doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalled JDK and now everything works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with steps you have done.

1. create Main.java

   `public class Main {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println("Hello World!");
     }
   }`
2. compile with `javac Main.java` you get Main.class
3. create mainfest file manifest.mf with content

   `Main-Class: Main`
4. create jar file with `jar -cvfm test.jar manifest.mf Main.class`
5. execute `java -jar test.jar` and the output is
   `Hello World!`

P.S: steps were executed on MacOS too, but it doesn't depend on OS.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, but it doesn't help with the problem I'm having. The cause must be something else.

Comment: Just an idea: You don't have any blanks in path to your directory, where all files are located? Are you able to execute Main.class directly e.g. `java Main`?

Comment: Yes, the program runs fine It just seems it can't find the files